# Laravel 4 content yielded before layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using a fresh build today of Laravel 4.

I have a dashboardController

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = 'layouts.dashboard';

public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('dashboard.default');
    }

}
```

I have a simple route

```
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
```

I have a blade layout in views/layouts/dashboard.blade.php
For the sake of saving everyone from all of the actual HTML ill use a mock up.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

I have a default blade file in views/dashboard/ that has the following (edited for simplicity)

```
@section('content')
<p>This is not rocket science</p>
@stop
```

For some reason the content gets generated before the layout.

Comment: Is your BaseController doing anything special?  Make sure it has the `setupLayout()` method: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php -- Otherwise, you may needt o post more of your dashboard.default file.

Comment: Yeah, check the `setupLayout()` on `BaseController`. I just set up a 1:1 environment with what you've posted here and it works (at least I suppose it does - you have not provided expected result, and actual result). You could also try `$this->layout->nest('content', 'dashboard.default')` instead of `$this->layout->content`...

Answer (score 4):

I am using a different approach to set the layouts globally to routes using a custom filter. Put the following filter into the app/filters.php

```
Route::filter('theme', function($route, $request, $response,  $layout='layouts.default')
{
    // Redirects have no content and errors should handle their own layout.
    if ($response->getStatusCode() > 300) return;

    //get original view object
    $view = $response->getOriginalContent();

    //we will render the view nested to the layout
    $content = View::make($layout)->nest('_content',$view->getName(), $view->getData())->render();

    $response->setContent($content);
});
```

and now instead of setting layout property in the controller class, you can group the routes and apply the filter as shown below.

```
Route::group(array('after' => 'theme:layouts.dashboard'), function()
{

    Route::get('/admin', 'DashboardController@getIndex');

    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', function(){ return View::make('dashboard.default'); });

});
```

When creating the views, make sure to use the @section('sectionName') in all the sub views and use @yield('sectionName') in the layout views.

Comment: This seems like a very advanced concept, did you come up with it yourself of found in the wilderness of the internets? *Maybe there are some more advanced stuff out there*

Comment: Hi @jolt, I think I took the idea from the Laravel forum, however that was specific to Laravel 3 and slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to do my layout like this for example. I would create my master blade file like so

```
<html>
    <body>
      @yield('content');
    </body>
</html
```

And in the blade files that I want to use the master at the top i would put

```
@extends('master')
```

then content like so

```
@section('content')
 // content
@stop
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you use controller layouts, i.e. `$this->layout->...`, then you get access to data as variables, not sections.  So to access content in your layout you should use...

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And in your partial, you would not use `@section` or `@stop`...

```
<p>This is not rocket science</p>
```